# Good way of getting version from package.json

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-scripts

I am developing a sdk that will be available on npm.

The sdk should be able to deliver its version to the client. I would like this version to be the same as the package.json version.

But when in my sdk I put `import {version} from '../package.json'`, I see that ALL package.json is added to the build.

Is there a good way of getting the version or will I be forced to set the version variable in my sdk with something like a bash script on `npm version` ? Or how would you do this ?

Comment: Thank you @RobC that did the trick ! And it should work very well in continuous integration.

Comment: It seems that I don't have enough reputation to upvote comments... If you mind you could write an answer that I could upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by specifying a placeholder text string within your JavaScript file. Lets say we have a file named `build.js` and within that file we have a variable named `VERSION` declared as follows:

```js
// build.js
const VERSION = '@VERSION@'
```

As you can see, the placeholder text string is `@VERSION@`.

You can then install and utilize the package called [replace](https://github.com/harthur/replace) in an [npm-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) as follows:

1. To install `replace` you'll need to `cd` to your project directory and run:

   ```js
   npm install replace --save-dev
   ```
2. Then add the following to the `scripts` section of to your `package.json`:

   ```json
   {
     ...
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "scripts": {
       "add-version":  "replace -s \"@VERSION@\" $npm_package_version build/build.js",
       "prepublishOnly": "npm run add-version"
     }
   }
   ```

**Running:**

When you run the following command via your CLI to publish your package:

```
$ npm publish
```

the `prepublishOny` script (which is a [pre hook](http://www.marcusoft.net/2015/08/pre-and-post-hooks-for-npm-scripting.html)) will be invoked which in turn will invoke the `add-version` script.

The `add-version` script will replace the instance of `@VERSION@` with the package version (i.e. `1.0.0`), in the file named `build.js`. This solution will hard-code the npm package version into the resultant file.

---

**Cross Platform**

The *to* string in the `add-version` script (above) currently uses the `$` prefix (i.e. `$npm_package_version`) to access the variable, so this will only run successfully on a bash shell.

However, for cross-platform usage you'll need to use [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var).

1. To install `cross-var` you'll need to `cd` to your project directory and run:

   ```
   npm install cross-var --save-dev
   ```
2. Then redefine the `add-version` script as follows:

   ```json
   {
     ...
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "scripts": {
       "add-version":  "cross-var replace -s \"@VERSION@\" $npm_package_version build/build.js",
       "prepublishOnly": "npm run add-version"
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nodejs, I think you could save your environment and your app-version in an independent environment file. For example, I save my setting on a file named .env and read them by using an npm module called [dotenv](http://npm.im/dotenv)

Comment: I'm not using node unfortunately. It's just a basic js object with some functions inside